# ¿Cómo puede hacer que RStudio me cargue paquetes automáticamente cuando abro un Project?

Tags: r, rstudio

Quisiera saber como le indico a `RStudio` para que me cargue las siguientes librerías de forma automática cuando abro el proyecto:

```
#Importando Librerías
library(lubridate)
library(ggalt)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(hms)
library(tidytext)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma sencilla es crear un nuevo archivo de texto llamado `.Rprofile` en la misma carpeta dónde tienes el archivo `.Rprj` de tu proyecto. En el mismo ingresa la secuencia de carga de los paquetes que necesites:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggalt)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(hms)
library(tidytext)
```

La siguiente vez que abras tu proyecto, deberían cargarse automáticamente estos paquetes.

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si la respuesta funcionó @Fidel E. Morla M. sugiero que sea acepta, [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) esto no sólo aumentará tus puntos y la posibilidad de que ganes más medallas, sino que permitirá a la comunidad estar enfocada en ayudar a otros miembros con las preguntas no resueltas.